# How to run script as php user

Tags: shell, ubuntu, permissions, php7

I have a script which is called from php using the `shell_exec` command on a server running Ubuntu. The script runs properly when called from the command line via ssh, but not when called from php.

I'm having a really hard time figuring out where it is going wrong and I was wondering if there was a way to run the script from the ssh command line but with the same user account and permissions that php `shell_exec` will call it with.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the php user is `www-data`:

```
sudo -u www-data /path/to/script
```

The environment may be different but that probably does not matter.

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me hours of trying to find out what was going (a permissions issue)